# Mutual exclusion between argument groups

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to implement the following argument dependency using the argparse module:
`./prog [-h | [-v schema] file]`
meaning the user must pass either -h or a file, if a file is passed the user can optionally pass -v schema.

That's what I have now but that doesn't seem to be working:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
mtx = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
mtx.add_argument('-h', ...)  
grp = mtx.add_argument_group()
grp.add_argument('-v', ...)
grp.add_argument('file', ...)   
args = parser.parse_args()
```

It looks like you can't add an arg group to a mutex group or am I missing something?

Comment: Just so you know `-h` is included by default, you don't need to add it yourself.

Comment: Is there really a `)` after the second `grp.add_argument`? Other than that, your approach should work (you might want to set `required=True` in the mutex group).

Comment: What is `-h` supposed to represent? Ordinarily, an argument starting with `-` should be strictly optional. It seems to me that whatever `-h` represents should simply be the default behavior *unless* an optional positional argument `file` is supplied. No `-h` option is needed, and `-v` can simply be ignored if no `file` argument is given.

Comment: -h is just an argument example. You could rename it to -x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `-h` means the default help, then this is all you need (this help is already exclusive)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file')
parser.add_argument('-s','--schema')
parser.parse_args('-h'.split())  # parser.print_help()
```

producing

```
usage: stack23951543.py [-h] [-s SCHEMA] file
...
```

If by `-h` you mean some other action, lets rename it `-x`. This would come close to what you describe

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s','--schema', default='meaningful default value')
mxg = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
mxg.add_argument('-x','--xxx', action='store_true')
mxg.add_argument('file', nargs='?')
parser.parse_args('-h'.split())
```

usage is:

```
usage: stack23951543.py [-h] [-s SCHEMA] (-x | file)
```

Now `-x` or `file` is required (but not both).  `-s` is optional in either case, but with a meaningful default, it doesn't matter if it is omitted.  And if `-x` is given, you can just ignore the `-s` value.

If necessary you could test `args` after parsing, to confirm that if `args.file` is not None, then `args.schema` can't be either.

---

Earlier I wrote (maybe over thinking the question):

An `argument_group` cannot be added to a `mutually_exclusive_group`.  The two kinds of groups have different purposes and functions.  There are previous SO discussions of this (see 'related'), as well as a couple of relevant Python bug issues.  If you want tests that go beyond a simple mutually exclusive group, you probably should do your own testing after `parse_args`.  That may also require your own `usage` line.

An `argument_group` is just a means of grouping and labeling arguments in the help section.

A `mutually_exclusive_group` affects the `usage` formatting (if it can), and also runs tests during `parse_args`.  The use of 'group' for both implies that they are more connected than they really are.

http://bugs.python.org/issue11588 asks for nested groups, and the ability to test for 'inclusivity' as well.  I tried to make the case that 'groups' aren't general enough to express  all the kinds of testing that users want.  But it's one thing to generalize the testing mechanism, and quite another to come up with an intuitive API.  Questions like this suggest that `argparse` does need some sort of 'nested group' syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Naturally I though groups and mutex groups can be nested to define more complex command syntax.

Comment: You are not alone.  But I don't know if it's simpler to refine the documentation, or to extend the power of `groups` in the code.  Fundamentally the `parser` works with a flat list of arguments (`parser._actions`).  When an argument is added to a group it is also added to that parser list.  The group keeps its own list, but only for special purposes like formatting.