# Argparse mutally exclusive by subgrouping

Tags: python, argparse

Currently the argparse of my code gives the following:

```
usage: ir.py [-h] [-q  | --json | -d ]

Some text

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -q                    gene query terms (e.g. mcpip1)
  --json                output in JSON format, use only with -q
  -d , --file_to_index  file to index
```

What I want it to do is the following:

1. `-q` should be mutually exclusive from `-d`
2. and `--json` should only go with `-q`

What's the way go go about it?
This is my argparse code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''Some text''')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-q",help="gene query terms (e.g. mcpip1)",metavar="",type=str)
group.add_argument("--json", help="output in JSON format, use only with -q", action="store_true")
group.add_argument("-d","--file_to_index", help="file to index",metavar="",type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

It currently rejects `-q` with `--json`:

```
python ir.py --json -q mcpip1
usage: ir.py [-h] [-q  | --json | -d ]

ir.py: error: argument -q: not allowed with argument --json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-q` and `-d` aren't really options (presumably, one them is required); they're subcommands, so you should use the subparser feature of `argparse` to create two subcommands `query` and `index`, and associate `--json` only with the `query` subcommand.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''Some text''')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

query_p = subparsers.add_parser("query", help="Query with a list of terms")
query_p.add_argument("terms")
query_p.add_argument("--json", help="output in JSON format, use only with -q", action="store_true")

index_p = subparsers.add_parser("index", help="index a file")
index_p.add_argument("indexfile", help="file to index")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Help for the overall program is available with

```
ir.py -h
```

Help for each subcommand is displayed separately

```
ir.py query -h
ir.py index -h
```

Usage would be something like

```
ir.py query "list of terms"
ir.py query --json "list of terms"
ir.py index somefile.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to add `--json` to the `parser`, rather than the `group`, and ignore it when it isn't needed.  You could also write a custom usage, if you don't think your help lines are sufficient.

Also don't be afraid to test for co-occurance or exclusion of arguments after `parse_args`.  As you can see on the sidebar, there are lots of questions about `mutually_exclusvie_groups`.  Often the desired logic goes beyond what a simple grouping API can provide.

And if it fits your desired syntax, `subparsers` give you more power to mix and match arguments.

A longer answer on a similar question is [Mutual exclusion between argument groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951543/mutual-exclusion-between-argument-groups/23955452#23955452)

Ideally what would your `usage` line look like?
Is `--json` required with `-q` or just allowed?